# c++ classes, const function that calls non constant function

Tags: c++

in C++ classes, if I have a constant function (In my understanding constant functions are classes that cannot change anyting in the class, hope this is true)
for example a function like this

```
int output(int value) const
```

Am I allowed to call a function within this function remove that actually changes anything in the class?

For example lets say I have a variable called number in private.

my output function adds one to the variable number, but not directly, it calls
a non constant function called addOne which adds one to the variable number.
I notice that I am getting an error when a output function is calling addOne(I know that output function is const but it modifies a value, but it modifies it indirectly). I wonder why I am getting an error, what error compiler actually detects here?

Thank You, and sorry if my question is hard to understand.

Thank you all for answering.

Comment: Are you wondering why your function that promises not to change anything isn't allowed to change anything?

Comment: It is possible to indirectly modify an object through a const method, if you can find a non-const pointer to it from somewhere else.

Comment: @NeilKirk again a good point :) And this comes back to the old discussion of "bit-wise const" via "logical const".

Comment: @molbdnilo that is exactly what I was wondering about. I understand it sounds stupid, but I was curious because change was happening indirectly.

Comment: @user1335175 Along the lines of "I'm not allowed to have a cookie, but my brother is, so it should be OK if he takes one and gives it to me"? No, that's still not OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple - no, you cannot. Every class method is a function that implicitly passes `this` as a parameter. When you declare a method as const, that means that it will actually pass `const this` to this function. It is both  correct logically and syntactically not to call not const methods from const methods.

Comment: @vsoftco, yeah sure. It is a good point to use mutable members when you want to cache some calculations that is done in const methods in order to get a better response time.

Comment: Actually I take it back, you cannot call non-`const` member functions from inside `const` methods, no matter what. I misread the question, upvoted your answer.

Comment: You can actually `const_cast<Foo*>(this)` and call a `const` method, but it only works ok on non-`const` objects. On `const` objects it leads to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

const instances can only call const functions. Say:

```
class YourClass {

...
int output(int value) const;
int regularMethod(); // Non-const
...
};
```

is your class with a const function. And the variables:

```
const YourClass obj1;
YourClass obj2;
```

Here obj1 can call output method while it cant call regularMethod. obj2 can call both.

Comment: This answer is too vague. What is a "regular" instance? Also, you can have a non-const instance accessed through a const reference.

Comment: obj2 can call the output function.

Comment: @NeilKirk: It was my bad sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Every const function() is getting a `const this` pointer as a default parameter, so you cannot change a member variable  of a class even if you try to call a non_cost function from a const function and try to modify a member variable.

So if you try to call a non const function from a const function, you will get compile error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO. The long answer is perhaps YES, provided you use an abomination like this, via [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast)-ing `this` in the `const` calling function (but you have to make sure you invoke your function on non-`const` objects, otherwise it leads to undefined behaviour):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    int x = 0;
    void f()
    {
        ++x;
    }
    void modify_x() const
    {
        const_cast<Foo*>(this)->f(); // call non-const member function
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    std::cout << foo.x << std::endl;
    foo.modify_x();
    std::cout << foo.x << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer. Also thank you for additional clarification in regards to mutable, but at this point I never worked with mutable and have no idea what it is :).

Comment: @user1335175 actually I misread your question, and Anton's answer is the correct one, I clarified mine. `mutable` lets you modify non-`const` member variables via `const` methods. But it cannot allow calling non-`const` methods from inside `const` methods.